# Is there way to connect profiler OSE JAVA app pods?

Tags: java, profiling, openshift, jprofiler

- There is memory leak in my spring boot application
  It was able to take 70 concurrent request at ramup of 5seconds and it works smooth on my local machine

When I did deploy the same application on OSE it created out of memory issue

I was trying to connect java profiling tools to remote OPENSHIFT java pods?

Is there any procedure to collect the heap dump or connect profile tool(jvisualvm) to ose pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are manual ways of collecting the ThreadDump & HeapDump in out of memory situations

1. oc get pods - > List Pods
2. oc rsh pod -> Remote shell to pod
3. "jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap_dump1.hprof 1"   -> Running the JMAP command to collect the heap dump
4. "jcmd 1 Thread.print > threaddump.txt" -> Running jcmd to collect the thread  dump
5. oc volume dc/yourApp --add --claim-size 512M --mount-path  --name downloads -> Creating the persistent volumes

After connecting the pods manually, explicitly execute the commands on the ose terminal 3 & 4 
Till the application reaches the OOM & because of dump on the persistent volume logs will not be cleared

6. Copy the heapDump files & threadDump files from  OSE pod to Local fileSystem 
   after zipping them by "tar"

oc rsync